# AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS always returns the value zero (AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED)

Tags: android

I am using below code to check if my application has usage access enabled or not.

```
try {
   PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
   ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
   AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
   int mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
   return (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
   return false;
}
```

Above code always return the "true" value even though the usage access permission is disabled for my application.

IMP NOTE: This is only happening in Lenovo P1a42 device with OS version 5.1.1. In all other devices it works as stated in the official link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager.html

Is there any problem with the device or am I missing any conditions in my code?

Answer (score 1):

As I have mentioned that this behavior is observed only in the "Lenovo P1a42 device", so I cross verified it by installing the "My Data Manager" application (which uses "usage_access" permission like my application do) in the same device.

"My Data Manager" application is also prompts the user to enable "usage_access" permission to show per application network usage in the device. But in "Lenovo P1a42 device" this application also doesn't prompted the user to enable "usage_access" permission even though that permission was not granted.

So I think this test concludes the issue with the "Lenovo P1a42 device" itself.

Comment: This problem exists also with LG devices... :-(